# How to pass Control object in code behind

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, webforms, code-behind

C#/.Net 4.0, VS2013:
I have 3 tab controls in an aspx page (tabpanel in div tags), each contains a ReportViewer control, sample code below. I'm passing the tab id through PageMethods to the code behind because the 'onserverclick' isnt working for me. I'm getting the tabid based on which tab is clicked. Based on the tabid, I have populate the respective report in the tab.

```
  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="reportTabs" runat="server" >
      <li role="presentation" id="tab1" class="active" runat="server" ><a  href="#tab1" aria-controls="tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" >Tab 1</a></li>
      <li role="presentation" id="tab2" runat="server" ><a href="#tab2" aria-controls="tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" >Tab 2</a></li>
      <li role="presentation" id="tab2" runat="server"><a href="#tab2" aria-controls="tab3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" >Tab 3</a></li>
 </ul>`

<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="rep1" runat="server">
  <asp:UpdatePanel>
   <ContentTemplate>
       <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rv1" runat="server"
            Width="100%" Height="100%"
            WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" PageCountMode="Actual" AsyncRendering="false"
            SizeToReportContent="true"
            ShowPrintButton="False"  >
        </rsweb:ReportViewer>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

</div>
```

Since PageMethods has to be a static method, I couldnt be converting all methods to static, I created a Singleton object of the same class. In Page_Load, I'm assigning the report id to this singleton instance's report id. I could see the rdlc reportpath. So far good.

```
 private static Reports instance = new Reports();

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (!IsPostBack)
     {
         this.rv1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Report1.rdlc";
         instance.rv1 = this.rv1;
     }
 }
```

In another method, when I add the DataSource, the rv1 becomes null.

```
instance.rv1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);  // rv1 is null.
```

What am I doing wrong. Any other ways to achieve this.

Here's the WebMethod:

```
public static  TabChanged(string liElement)//object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            switch (liElement)
            {
                case "cpContent_tab3":
                    break;
                case "cpContent_tab1":
                    instance.PopulateRep1();
                    break;
                case "cpContent_tab2":
                    instance.PopulateRep2();
                    break;
            }
    }

    protected void PopulateRep1()
    {
        dt = GetReportDetails();
        if (dt != null)
        {
            ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("RepSummary", dt);
         // instance.rv1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Rep1.rdlc";          
            Instance.rv1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            instance.rv1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
        }
    }
```

Appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Where's the `WebMethod`? What means _" 'onserverclick' isnt working for me"_? In general you should not store controls in a static field. All page objects and controls are disposed at the end of the page's lifecycle.

Comment: The WebMethod is in the code behind. And the 'onserverclick' I placed in the 'li' tag under 'div', but that wasnt firing, and hence I resorted to the WebMethod. The WebMethod was called only to know which tab is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I would back up and sort out the 'onserverclick' issue. That will trigger a postback. That's critical because it's going to post your webform and viewstate back to the server so that you can interact with those controls on the server the  way you want to.

When you do that postback, the page's viewstate will be sent back to the server. The server will then "know" the state of the controls on the page and then it can manipulate them.

It's probably something minor you can sort out that's keeping your click event from firing. Once you get that fixed the rest will fall into place. But you can't "go around" that and find another way to interact with those server controls. There isn't one.